# Symbolication / 'atos' works on one machine but not on another

Tags: ios, crash, crash-reports, symbolicatecrash, plcrashreporter

I am trying to symbolicate iOS-crashlogs. I'm running QuincyKit as a server and PLCrashReporter as client-reporting tool.

Now whats really confusing is that the symbolication is working on my local machine but not on our server, which has a cronjob set up, to symbolicate all crashreports sent by the QuincyKit-server.
Both are running **XCode 7.2.1** and both are **OSX ElCapitan 10.11**.
The archive, which I'm using to generate crashes for testing has been generated on the server, so it has the **.xcarchive** AND the **.dsym** and **.app** files all available.

I'm running the following command:

```
atos -arch arm64 -l 0x10007c000 -o 'MyApp.app/MyApp' 0x00000001003b468c
```

When I run it on the server it just returns the hexcode that I entered like this:

```
0x00000001003b468c (in MyApp) + 0
```

Although when I run the exact same command on my local machine, on which I copied the **.app & .dsym** it returns something like this:

```
-[PLCrashReporter generateLiveReportWithThread:] (in MyApp) + 0
```

which is the symbolicated version of my hex-value.

I really don't have any clue anymore what could be different. The files are an exact copy from the files on the server

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?